# how to @use mixins once instead of every .scss file?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, scss-mixins

I have a main.scss:

```
@use "class-one.scss"
@use "class-two.scss"
@use "class-three.scss
```

and the folder:

```
assets
  scss
    _mixins.scss
    _class-one.scss
    _class-two.scss
    _class-three.scss
    main.scss
```

This works fine as long as I write `@use 'mixins'` inside ***every*** single 'class' file:

```
@use mixins;

.class-one {
  @include mixins.the-mixin;
}
```

What I would like try to is to @use 'mixins' once, in the main.scss preferably, but that gives me `Error: There is no module with the namespace "mixins".`

As I am using Nuxt 3, I also tried to import the mixins as

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@use "@/assets/scss/_mixins.scss" as mixins;'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

but get the same error.

Weirdly, if I add both the vite conf and @use 'mixins', it gives me `ERROR [sass] There's already a module with namespace "mixins".`

Answer (score 0):

Using `additionalData` is correct. I'm going to take a wild guess and say the problem here is that the alias in the path is not handled when injected with this option. Assuming `assets` is in `src/`, I suggest you try with this instead:

```js
additionalData: '@use "src/assets/scss/mixins";'
```

You don't need `_` and `.scss` in the path as it's handled natively by the preprocessor. You also don't need to specify the namespace as [by default it's the last component of the module’s URL](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/#loading-members).